# Backup mysql database in xampp?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Hello everyone recently I made a database and our professor told us that we can make a copy of the database by copying the  folder in xampp/mysql/data.

Then after i made my database I copied the folder of my database in there because I will continue making the database on another computer. It turns out that copying that folder along isnt enough, because it turns out that it can only read the database itself, but not the content of the tables in the database.

The content of the database folder "tablename".frm and  a "db.opt".

Can someone teach me the proper way to backup a database? and what is the files that i need to copy in order to run the database I made on other Computer.

I have already read this but I can't seem to understand the instructions properly.(if ever this is the right way to backup it)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-backup.html

Comment: did you copied the entire mysql folder, or at least `my.conf` file?

Comment: ARRGH!  The procedure your prof has suggested is suitable for skilled systems administrators handling large databases.  Even then it's a pain in the, umm, neck. If your class is about systems and database administration, then do what your prof says.  But for a programming project, you should export and import rather than trying to copy the DBMS server's InnoDB files.

Answer (score 27):

There is Two way to backup your database
**One:Folder backup** 
In windows go to xampp installation folder xampp> mysql > data > here you find your database name folder. copy it and save it .
 you can use any other computer just go to xampp installation folder xampp> mysql > data >paste it here. 
**Note:** You should not overwrite the MySql default folders and only overwrite 3 files

1. ibdata1
2. ib_logfile0
3. ib_logfile1

others should remain as default. Thanks otherewise you wont see your databases in PHPMyAdmin. Thanks

**Two:export database .sql backup** 
In browser go to phpmyadmin and select your database >then in to the top mane click Export. then write a name in New template input box .then click go  .you will find a file is down loaded.  
you can use it any other computer then go to phpmyadmin in browser and create a database and on the top menu click **Import**  click **choose file** > select this file witch is downloaded > then click **go** button.

Comment: i tried using method 1 but i am still not able to recover my databases, ive got all the data in mysql/data. but they still dont appear in my database even after copying them in the same folder to my new xampp folder

Comment: I think your database is not there. the only an empty folder is there. @Viscocent

Comment: @Viscocent You must not overwrite the default mysql folders you only need you database folder and 3 other files ib_log files and ibdata1

Comment: how to delete specific database which is have been corrupted?

Answer (score 12):

At Your local screen for XAMPP (Inside your browser), go to PhpMyAdmin (on the left hand side) and Select MySQL, See your database on the top left, ensure it is selected. In the center screen there will be a menu tab, where there is an Import and next to it Export tabs. Select the Export tab.
Here you will have to select all the tables you want to include in the backup, as well as set the name and set location for backup file (believe its the Download file by default). Remember to also ensure the type of backup file is selected. i.e. sql file etc.

After you have made this backup you can simply Import it again in XAMPP in your browser. should be relatively easy. Hope it helps.

Comment: do i need to have an internet to make a backup? when i tried to make one its trying to connect to the internet.

Comment: No its not supposed to be necessary. It should stay in the same page just load new content. It acts as an online process but its obviously all local.

Answer (score 3):

Use the export function in phpMyAdmin  https://wordpress.org/support/article/backing-up-your-database/

Comment: Be sure you select the DATA option

Answer (score 1):

These 3 files are the ones which contain the table content

1. ibdata1
2. ib_logfile0
3. ib_logfile1

so once you copy all the other part overwrite only these three files and your table content will be available